# How can I get Wordpress functioning from its new address?

Tags: mysql, apache-httpd, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress installation which I wish to redirect from http://dev.example.com to https://example.com

I can get an unstyled page like the below; the browser balks at loading HTTP content for an HTTPS page.[image: A CSS-less screenshot].

Since I began trying the migration, I have never succeeded in loading `/wp-admin`: it seems to run into a redirect loop. Commenting out Apache configuration files' `RewriteRules` did not make any difference I can tell.

How can I tell Wordpress to serve up files the obvious way when someone tries to log in to the admin interface?

I'd ideally like command line MySQL to fix it.

Comment: Did you change address in Wordpress admin panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this fix for me,

add these lines into your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

where both entries contain your new site address.

Restart webserver

Comment: Thank you; I had tried that while composing my response. The homepage source attempts to load both HTTP and HTTPS URLs. (I can post the source for an HTTP load of the page if that would help; I was trying to be courteous and not post links that didn't need to be posted, which may or may not have been the right choice on my side.